# Spring Boot + Angular app deployed to Heroku as a WAR, throws 404 unless I include "index.html" in the URL

Tags: angular, spring-boot, tomcat, heroku, webapp-runner

I'm trying to create a very basic Spring Boot + Angular application, which I would then be able to develop and have automatically deployed as a single application. To build the application, I configured Maven to compile the Angular project and add it to a WAR file along with my backend. Then it deploys the WAR to Heroku which launches it using the following web dyno:

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/Springular-1.0.war
```

I'm using Webapp Runner which launches a Tomcat instance with the given WAR.

The Angular part itself is built using a postinstall script in package.json:

```
"postinstall": "ng build --prod --base-href /ui/"
```

As you can see, I've set up base-href to "/ui/" here and in pom.xml. I mapped my Spring Controller to "/api". I expected to be able to access my frontend with `https://app.herokuapp.com/ui` and make backend requests like for example `https://app.herokuapp.com/api/hello-world`.

While the backend part works fine, when I try to access the UI I'm being met with a 404 Whitelabel Error Page. My webapp folder (src/main/webapp) looks like this:

```
springular 
└───src
    └───main
        └───webapp
            │   index.jsp
            └───WEB-INF
                │   web.xml
```

web.xml doesn't contain any configuration. index.jsp sends a redirect to "/ui/". If I change the redirect to "/ui/index.html", I can access my frontend with the URL `https://app.herokuapp.com/`, but when I refresh the page I get a 404 again.

Things I've tried so far:

- Setting an Angular route for '' (empty) path - didn't help but I've kept it anyway.
- Adding `server.servlet.context-path` to Spring properties instead of using @RequestMapping annotation.
- Disabling Whitelabel Error Page in Spring's application.properties, which resulted in getting a different error about not handling errors.
- Specifying an error page location in web.xml. It didn't change anything.
- Overriding SpringBootServletInitializer's configure method in main Java class.
- Using hash location strategy in Angular (`RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })`)

From what I've read so far, my best guess is my Tomcat is not properly configured, but I don't know how to fix it. If it makes things easier, I'm willing to ditch the "/ui/" part from frontend URLs.

Lastly, I'll include some files I think might be relevant to the issue.

**index.jsp**

```
<% response.sendRedirect("/ui"); %>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <display-name>Springular</display-name>
</web-app>
```

**Main Spring Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringularApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringularApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Springular</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>springular</name>
    <description>Spring + Angular Template Application</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <heroku.appName>springular-template</heroku.appName>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}\frontend\dist</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}\frontend</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                          <nodeVersion>v12.16.2</nodeVersion>
                          <npmVersion>6.14.4</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                          <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install angular</id>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                          <arguments>install @angular/cli@^9.0.0 -g</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.heroku</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>9.0.41.0</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>frontend/dist/springular</directory>
                            <targetPath>ui</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals><goal>deploy-war</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <appName>${heroku.appName}</appName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try hash location strategy as follows in your app module,

```
providers: [
        {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
]
```